# Performance overhead of UseAdaptiveSizePolicy

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I'm observing very long stop-the-world pauses when my application is changing ratio between Eden and Survivor Spaces. I'm not using any custom JVM flags, so `UseAdaptiveSizePolicy` is enabled by default. Host has 32 GB of RAM. I have JDK 8.

```
Eden Space: used = 833208K, max = 1263616K
Survivor Space: used = 634357K, max = 634368K
Old Gen: used = 2456700K, max = 5480448K
(11s stop-the-world)
Eden Space: used = 24665K, max = 1105920K
Survivor Space: used = 297749K, max = 842240K
Old Gen: used = 3094701K, max = 5480448K
```

In my case it took JVM 11 s to decrease Eden by ~100 MB, increase Survivor by ~200 MB and tenure about ~600 MB of objects. Are these really so costly operations? What could have happened?

Here is log from the GC:

```
2017-10-19T10:24:28.845+0100: 201.951: [Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 337425K->60051K(1966080K)] [ParOldGen: 2877063K->3135388K(4417536K)] 3214488K->3195440K(6383616K), [Metaspace: 85871K->85871K(1126400K)], 11.0121325 secs] [Times: user=45.02 sys=2.24, real=10.01 secs]
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the first thing to do is to enable detailed logging `-XX:+PrintGCDetails`.

Comment: you may be confounding cause and effect. but as the other comment says, detailed GC logs would be needed to say more

Comment: I've added log to the question, thanks for the tips, but I need further help